# processStudents.then is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert Callback function to Promise. But I'm getting this error that processStudents is not a function. How can I convert it to promise. Thankyou.

```
let students = [
  { name: "Ahmad1", score: 10, school: "East" },
  { name: "Ahmad2", score: 20, school: "East" },
  { name: "Ahmad3", score: 30, school: "East" },
  { name: "Ahmad4", score: 40, school: "West" },
  { name: "Ahmad5", score: 50, school: "East" },
  { name: "Ahmad6", score: 60, school: "West" },
  { name: "Ahmad7", score: 70, school: "East" },
];

let processStudents = function (data, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].school.toLowerCase() === "east") {
      if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback(data[i]);
      }
    }
  }
};

processStudents(students, function (obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (obj.score > 20) {
      resolve("Success");
    } else {
      reject("Failed");
    }
  });
});

processStudents.then((message) => {
  console.log(message);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: processStrudents is a function, not a promise ... processStudents doesn't even return anything - and it uses a function `callback` which isn't declared

Comment: Also, why do you need it to return a promise? Is is meant to make any API calls, for example? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that you always run callback function and `processStudents.then` there is no parameter and callback function!